# How do have unique variables for each dynamically created buttons/text fields?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create buttons and vue element inputs for each item on the page. I'm iterating through the items and rendering them with `v-for` and so I decided to expand on that and do it for both the rest as well. The problem i'm having is that I need to to bind `textInput` as well as `displayTextbox` to each one and i'm not sure how to achieve that.

currently all the input text in the el-inputs are bound to the same variable, and clicking to display the inputs will display them all at once.

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <icon @click="showTextbox"/>
            <el-input v-if="displayTextbox" v-model="textInput" />
            <el-button v-if="displayTextbox" type="primary" @click="confirm" />
            <ItemDisplay :data-id="item.id" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ItemDisplay from '@/components/ItemDisplay';

export default {
    name: 'ItemList',

    components: {
        ItemDisplay,
    },

    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    }

    data() {
        displayTextbox = false,
        textInput = '',
    },

    methods: {
        confirm() {
            // todo send request here
            this.displayTextbox = false;
        },

        showTextbox() {
            this.displayTextbox = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: with the help of @kissu here's the updated and working version

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in itemDataList" :key="itemDataList.id">
            <icon @click="showTextbox(item.id)"/>
            <El-Input v-if="item.displayTextbox" v-model="item.textInput" />
            <El-Button v-if="item.displayTextbox" type="primary" @click="confirm(item.id)" />
            <ItemDisplay :data-id="item.item.uuid" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ItemDisplay from '@/components/ItemDisplay';

export default {
    name: 'ItemList',

    components: {
        ItemDisplay,
    },

    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    }

    data() {
        itemDataList = [],
    },

    methods: {
        confirm(id) {
            const selected = this.itemDataList.find(
                (item) => item.id === id,
            )
            selected.displayTextbox = false;
            console.log(selected.textInput);
            // todo send request here
        },

        showTextbox(id) {
            this.itemDataList.find(
                (item) => item.id === id,
            ).displayTextbox = true;
        },
        
        populateItemData() {
            this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                this.itemDataList.push({
                    id: item.uuid + index,
                    displayTextbox: false,
                    textInput: '',
                    item: item,
                });
            });
        }
    },

    created() {
        // items prop is obtained from parent component vuex
        // generate itemDataList before DOM is rendered so we can render it correctly
        this.populateItemData();
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you use an array of `displayTextbox` for the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[assuming you're using Vue2]
If you want to interact with multiple `displayTextbox` + `textInput` state, you will need to have **an array of objects** with a specific key tied to each one of them like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903151/8816585).
As of right now, you do have only 1 state for them all, meaning that as you can see: you can toggle it for all or none only.

You'll need to refactor it with an object as in my above example to allow a case-per-case iteration on each state individually.

PS: `:key="index"` is not a valid solution, you should never use the `index` of a `v-for` as [explained here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/understanding-the-key-attribute#dont-use-an-index-as-the-key).
PS2: please follow [the conventions](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#component-name-casing-in-templates) in terms of component naming in your template.

---

Also, I'm not sure how deep you were planning to go with your components since we don't know the internals of `<ItemDisplay :data-id="item.id" />`.
But if you also want to manage [the labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for each of your inputs, you can do that with [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid), that way you will be able to have unique UUIDs for each one of your inputs, quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store the values, like this:

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <el-input v-model="textInputs[index]" />
    </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        textInputs: []
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this out and it works for the textbox inputs which was great but i still needed other variables too. kissu's answer was able to point me in the direction i needed.